# I get an error while trying to install Ride

Tags: python, installation, robotframework

I get an error when I type the command to install Robotframework ride on my Debian :

```
pip3 install robotframework--ride
```

The error is :

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pywin32 (from robotframework--ride) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Pywin32 (from robotframework--ride)
```

Btw, it is quite strange that `Pywin32` is mentionned while I'm not on Windows... I have both `python2 and`python3` on my machine and I've read many topics where I saw it could bring about problems so it may be the reason I have this error...

Answer (score 1):

can you please try the following two steps mentioned below?
According to this [RIDE-doc](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/ride-1.7.3.1.rst), one needs to do the following if they are not on windows.

Excerpt from release notes

> NOTE: The installation process mentioned in
>   the [RIDE-RELEASE-NOTES](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/ride-1.7.3.1.rst) is only working smoothly on Windows.

For other operating systems is better to do a two step install, with:

```
pip install -U -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robotframework/RIDE/master/requirements.txt
pip install -U robotframework-ride
```

Answer (score 1):

That problem was fixed in versions not yet released.
See [Release Notes for v1.7.4b2](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/ride-1.7.4.rst) on recommendations to install. Please install wxPython before.

A new version will be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

- pip install -U -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robotframework/RIDE/master/requirements.txt
- pip install -U robotframework-ride

Try the above installation.

pip3 install robotframework--ride is only for Windows according to instruction given. Apparently Pywin32 is for creating desktop shortcut in windows.