# I don't manage to install Robotframework Ride on my Debian

Tags: debian, robotframework, pywin32, robotframework-ide

When I type in my terminal :

```
sudo pip3 install robotframework-ride
```

I get this error :

```
Collecting robotframework-ride
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/a6/1835a17fa566b19c166735a9a75d55101e53b68566771ddb0b690dd4be83/robotframework_ride-1.7.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting robotframeworklexer (from robotframework-ride)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/18/ad01d42227d824b890f1b4d32237e5003bf7afe8764cb13545fb63d7fcb5/robotframeworklexer-1.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Pypubsub==3.3.0 (from robotframework-ride)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/5a/1801be1a63af9250e79b8941a37b88e3ca0d660b880b9862fe9016ae6a3a/PyPubSub-3.3.0.zip
Collecting Pygments (from robotframework-ride)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/39/32da3184734730c0e4d3fa3b2b5872104668ad6dc1b5a73d8e477e5fe967/Pygments-2.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting robotframework (from robotframework-ride)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/0f/1b9ffa0c4e59789b50e6034866e823b7d4a5c7eaedad7bfd0bba42f2aa9d/robotframework-3.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Pywin32 (from robotframework-ride)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pywin32 (from robotframework-ride) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Pywin32 (from robotframework-ride)
```

Anybody knows how to fix this ? I don't understand why it tells me that it can't find Pywin32 while I'm on Debian.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I get an error while trying to install Ride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372509/i-get-an-error-while-trying-to-install-ride)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [RIDE-doc](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/ride-1.7.3.1.rst), one needs to do the following if they are not on windows.

Excerpt from release notes

> NOTE: The installation process mentioned in
>   the [RIDE-RELEASE-NOTES](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/ride-1.7.3.1.rst) is only working smoothly on Windows.

For other operating systems is better to do a two step install, with:

```
pip install -U -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robotframework/RIDE/master/requirements.txt
pip install -U robotframework-ride
```

NOTE: This problem is fixed in [Release](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/ride-1.7.4.rst) v1.7.4b2, read this for the recommendations to install.